# Evaluate the sum $\sum_{0\leq j < k\leq n}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Could someone give me a hint on how to do this? I believe I know what the answer to be (I computed some low values and checked on OEIS). However, I was hoping someone would be able to explain to me how to approach a question like this.

Comment: Have you tried the snake oil method with generating functions?

Comment: I am only familiar with that method by name. However, I was hoping to use a more basic tool to evaluate this as in the book I got this exercise from did not cover Generating Functions at that point yet.

Comment: Was that supposed to be double sigma?

Comment: It is the sum all over $(j,k)$ such that $0\leq j <k\leq n$. If it helps, I believe you can think of it as $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{k}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sum looks like the cross product terms of
$$\left[\binom n0+\binom n1+\cdots+\binom nn\right]^2.$$
Since
$$2^n=\binom n0+\binom n1+\cdots+\binom nn,$$
squaring both sides gives us
$$2^{2n}=\binom n0^2+\binom n1^2+\cdots+\binom nn^2+2\sum_{j\lt k}\binom nj\binom nk.$$
Since
$$\binom n0^2+\binom n1^2+\cdots+\binom nn^2=\binom n0\binom nn+\binom n1\binom n{n-1}+\cdots+\binom nn\binom n0=\binom{2n}n$$
(Vandermonde's identity), the previous equation simplifies to
$$2^{2n}=\binom{2n}n+2\sum_{j\lt k}\binom nj\binom nk$$
which we can solve to get your answer:
$$\sum_{j\lt k}\binom nj\binom nk=\frac{2^{2n}-\binom{2n}n}2.$$

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you meant : $\sum\sum_{0\le j<k\le n}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{k}$

$A=\sum_{j\le n}\sum_{k\le n}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{k} $

$B=\sum\binom{n}{i}^2$

You want $\dfrac{A-B}{2}$

$B=\binom{2n}{n}$ as it is coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^{n}\times(1+x)^n$

$A=\sum2^n\binom{n}{k}=2^{2n}$

Comment: This looks fine except I think you meant $A=2^{2n}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Pavelshu Yeah... my bad.